# Angular ui bootstrap carousel won't slide after setting a slide's active property to true

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here's a fork of the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YNYRFpPTtae2VnrhenZf?p=preview) of uib-carousel on [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel).

I added a line in the controller after the for loop for populating $scope.slides:

```
$scope.slides[1].active = true;
```

I want to pre-select a certain slide, however, after adding this line, the uib-carousel stopped sliding.

This is the intended behaviour? Or am I going about setting the active slide the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Try to delay that operation wrapping it with $timeout()

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.slides[1].active = true;  
})
```

Your Plunker updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/9aT26y9q8ivr0Ebagdsa?p=preview

Comment: This indeed works. Thanks. So without the  timeout, does it fail to update the scope?